# mysql ORDER BY depending on column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-8

I have the table `client_contacts` like:

| id | client_id | contact_type_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | johndoe@gmail.com |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | +999 999 999 |
| 3 | .. | .. | .... |

In my `contact_types` table I have the following types:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | address |
| 2 | fixed phone |
| 3 | email |
| 4 | mobile |

I want the ability to sort all the contacts that are in the `data` column and by that, the possibility to sort with the `contact_type_id`. How to do it in **Laravel 8** with **Eloquent\Builder**? I am using paginate as well.

Some uses:
Sort ASC all the emails and furthermore the possibility to sort two contact_types like fixed phone ASC and mobile DESC.

In my client model, I have `hasMany()` to the `client_contacts` model.

Comment: Hi, I find your question a bit hard to understand(might be me)  Can you show an example of how you want the sorting to look like? If you already have code trying to fix this issue, could you share it? :)

Comment: you can use ->orderBy("contact_type_id", "ASC")

Comment: @Hicham AIT TALGHALIT contact_type_id will put all addresses first

Comment: @RobBiermann My frontend checks the contact_type_id and put in a column, so my client can have many different contacts, they want to sort the addresses/fixed phones/ email and mobile. But these values are in the same column `data`

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

MYSQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

LARAVEL:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#orderbyraw

You can Add This Quote Of Code:

```
->orderByRaw("FIELD(contact_types.description, 'addresses', 'fixed phones', 'email', 'mobile') ASC")
```

Comment: `field` function returns the index position of the string or number matching the given pattern, the given solution will not order by emails, mobile, fixed phones nor addresses

Comment: i try the `field` it works , just you put the order that you want after the `contact_types.description` column. 
->orderByRaw("FIELD(contact_types.description, 'addresses', 'fixed phones', 'email', 'mobile') ASC")
will order `addresses` then `fixes mobiles` then `email` then `mobile`.
change it to your order